# executeUpdate is running indefinitely for oracle 12c

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle12c

I have a the following update query java code that very well in oracle 11 but for some reason executeUpdate is running indefinitely for oracle 12.

```
for (String strField : hmColumnData.keySet()) {
    String strUpdateQuery = "UPDATE MODEL_DATA SET " + strField + " = ? WHERE CONNECTION_ID = ?";

    try {
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(strUpdateQuery);
        Clob clob = conn.createClob();
        if (clob != null) {
            String dataString = hmColumnData.get(strField);
            dataString = dataString == null ? "" : dataString;
            clob.setString(1, "Test string");
            pStmt.setClob(1, clob);
        }
        pStmt.setLong(2, iConnId);
        pStmt.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.error("Error occured while updating the CLOB data field from the DataBase", e);
        conn.rollback();
    }
}
```

Following is the thread dump of that particular thread.

```
"model-thread-0" #407 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002ba43000 nid=0x558c runnable [0x000000007c71e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:282)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:122)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:78)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1179)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530)
        - locked <0x000000062378b910> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.mapper.init.eQModelDataManager.updateClobData(eQModelDataManager.java:731)
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.mapper.init.eQModelWriteObserverImpl.updateSemanticDataInDB(eQModelWriteObserverImpl.java:123)
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.mapper.init.eQModelWriteObserverImpl.saveCustomXML(eQModelWriteObserverImpl.java:156)
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.modelutil.ModelLoaderTask.b(ModelLoaderTask.java:120)
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.modelutil.ModelLoaderTask.execute(ModelLoaderTask.java:67)
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.concurrent.AbstractThread.run(AbstractThread.java:279)
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.concurrent.wrapper.RunnableWrapper.execute(RunnableWrapper.java:30)
        at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.concurrent.AbstractThread.run(AbstractThread.java:279)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x0000000685d9b8b0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

To verify that data that I am writing is not causing the issue I modified the string.

I tried to commit on the connection before using it, just to verify if some other transaction changes are on hold, still it was stuck.

I have no idea what am I missing neither do I have much knowledge in database, so please give me some direction.

Comment: Well, this: "I tried to commit on the connection before using it, just to verify if some other transaction changes are on hold" won't work. You can't commit other transactions, it is *them* who have to do that.

Comment: @Littlefoot - Yes you are absolutely right, but as this is a legacy code which cant be debugged easily and for finding if this was the issue, I tried this case. As if this was the case then I should be looking in some other part of the code

Comment: First see if its a performance issue or a blocking issue.  While it is running, query V$SESSION for your application and check the LOCKWAIT and BLOCKING_SESSION columns. If they are non-null, then someone is blocking you. If they are null, then its a performance issue and we can work from there